# IOEXCEPTION error again and again in FXML . Trying to put FXML file on a list element in ListView

Tags: java, exception, fxml

```
public class PopupController  {
    public ListView<String> listView;
    public Button addWalletButton;
    public PieChart piechart;
    public Label size;
    private WalletModel walletModel = Factory.inject(WalletModel.class);

    @FXML
    public void initialize() throws IOException {


        listView.setCellFactory(param -> new EditableCell());
        addWalletButton.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            walletModel.CreateWallet();
            listView.getFixedCellSize();
            listView.getItems().add("Wallet " + walletModel.WalletSize());
            size.setText("Total Wallets:  " + walletModel.WalletSize());
        });
        size.setText("Wallet Size " + walletModel.WalletSize());
        listView.getItems().add("Wallet 1");
    }

    private class EditableCell extends ListCell<String>{

        private final TextField textField;

        EditableCell() throws IOException {
            textField = new TextField();
            setGraphic(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/selectbutton.fxml")));
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if(empty){
                textField.setVisible(false);
            }
            else{
                textField.setVisible(true);
                textField.setText(item);
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Its showing error in the first statement in initialize() method.

I am trying to put a `fxml` file on a list element by button ("add wallet"). I have attached my `fxml` code below.

I am not receiving the stacktrace , because it shows compilation error

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="69.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.gazman.coco.desktop.controllers.PopupController">
    <Button fx:id="select" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button"/>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: What's the stacktrace? Please edit your question to help others to help you.

Comment: its not compiling actually , so i dont have the stack trace now

Comment: Okay, can you post the full error then?

Comment: Error:(23, 42) java: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown 
just this only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IOException` is a checked exception, which means it has to be explicitely handled in either of two ways:

- caught in the `catch` clause of a `try-catch` statement
- propagated by the method where the exeption might happen. This is done by adding `throws IOException` to the end of the signature of your method.

This is for forcing developers to handle typical failures for IO and other operations with a reasonable expectation of external failure.

Comment: thankyou, fr your suggestion , i tried that . but its not working

Comment: It has to work, if you apply these rules correctly. Do you have an IDE? It will help you resolve this type of issues.

Comment: ,it worked thanks.but it didnt work by second method. I implemented the first one. ThanksAgain.

Comment: Cool, feel free to accept the answer then :) And pay attention to how you handle exceptions, it's a very important part of a program

Comment: okay, just started working, didnt pay much to those before, but now i will

Comment: hi @Dici, could you please help me with how to add customized list elements from a fxml file . I have pasted the fxml file also below. I just want a texg field and a button as a list element.

Comment: Hi, you probably want to post another question if you have a different issue

Comment: Hi @ Dici, I tried but StackOverflow is not allowing me to post another question.

Comment: Are you sure? What is preventing you to do so?

Comment: yeah, this is what is showing (You've asked 3 questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account from asking questions entirely. It's been 2 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait 7 days before asking again. Use this time to revisit your previous questions, editing to address any issues that folks have pointed out in comments. )

Comment: I guess that means your questions didn't have high enough quality. Did you properly research before posting them? Did you include all the information required for people to help you? Did you format your code properly? etc I suggest that you make sure your next question meets these criteria.

Comment: I have asked the question again, and here is the link can you please have a look at it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52274295/javafx-listview-add-element-and-edit-the-property-of-a-particular-list-cell

Comment: Cool, give me some time

Comment: Can you undelete your question?

Comment: well, thanks for the time but I have resolved that issue it was not worth uploading so I deleted it

Comment: Ok, at least you fixed your issue ^^

Comment: I have another one, can you tell me  how and where I can tell you about my error and problem